# Is managed code slower than unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, .net

Its just a question out of my curiosity. Though generally considering the Framework and the steps involved in Execution, i'd say yes. Still i would also like to consider the factors like Memory/Disc access and networking which limit the performance of unmanaged code.

Comment: perhaps an internet search would help??? the answer is simply: No. And it depends.

Comment: In general, if you are doing network or disk-access, then the speed that something runs is probably limited to the speed of the disk or network. But it's impossible to say without either measurement or thorough understanding of the code (and how it translates to intermediate (.net bytecode) or machine language).

Comment: Write the code both ways, run it both ways, and then you'll know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Herb Sutter

*"First, JIT compilation isn’t the main issue. The root cause is much more fundamental: Managed languages made deliberate design tradeoffs to optimize for programmer productivity even when that was fundamentally in tension with, and at the expense of, performance efficiency."*

There’s always an inescapable and fundamental difference between “prevention” and “cure” — when it comes to performance optimization, C++ always chooses “prevention,” and managed languages choose “cure” with the above-mentioned heroic efforts and many more. But the old ounce/pound saying is inescapable; you can’t beat prevention (in part because you can always add the cure after first doing the prevention, but not the reverse), and if you care about performance and control primarily then you should use a language that is designed to prioritize that up front, that’s all.

You can refer this article for more clarity

http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/4026-the-war-at-microsoft-managed-v-unmanaged.html